# How much does science know about lightning?

Tags: atmospheric-science, lightning

In his Lectures, Feynman says the following:

> So the fundamental origin of lightning is really not thoroughly understood. We know it comes from the thunderstorms.

Source: http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_09.html

In general, Feynman emphasizes our lack of knowledge: for example, that we don't know how it comes to be that the tops of thunderstorms become positively charged while the bottoms are negatively charged.

Is Feynman exaggerating a lack of knowledge, or would other physicists agree with his general picture?

Comment: this topic is better-understood today than back when Feynman wrote that. Have you searched on wikipedia?